# JenkinsFile. sshPublisherDesc property

Tags: jenkins, ssh, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I attempting understand meaning sshPublisherDesc property from jenkins ssh publish plugin. Does anybody know what is it?

I checked docs (https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/publish-over-ssh/) but they don't containt any description about that. Could anyone to explain it for me a bit?

ps. All examples of using this plugin contain this property but i can't image what is it.

Answer (score 2):

It's the descriptor of each publisher, the api gives you this way to combine configName, transfers ...

https://github.com/jenkinsci/publish-over-ssh-plugin/blob/f75ee1db7a52f3cfddd138aae5149e02a4fc8258/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/publish_over_ssh/descriptor/BapSshPublisherDescriptor.java

Answer (score 1):

As I know this is ssh connection name for remote server
You will config it in the below image
Step 1:
[image]

Step 2: Add 2 sections
[image]
[image]

Step 3: Run Jenkins scripts with the above configuration

```
            script {
                sshPublisher(publishers: [sshPublisherDesc(configName: '10.90.9.11', transfers: [sshTransfer(cleanRemote: false, excludes: '', execCommand: 
                '''
                    sudo docker stop, start command.......
                ''', execTimeout: 120000, flatten: false, makeEmptyDirs: false, noDefaultExcludes: false, patternSeparator: '[, ]+', remoteDirectory: '', remoteDirectorySDF: false, removePrefix: '', sourceFiles: 'tmp')], usePromotionTimestamp: false, useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, verbose: false)])
            }
```

Hope to help you!

Comment: The screenshot is really helpful. Also please remember to add authentication in the "Advanced" option, here I need to input password for the ssh connection. Then after the configuration is completed, verify it by the "Test Configuration" option, if "Success" is shown, then the configuration is successful.